# ¿Cómo colocar requisitos previos para que un .exe se ejecute?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Me encargaron hacer un .exe, pero para que se pueda ejecutar hay que tener 2 programas instalados, pero hasta ahora no encuentro la forma de hacer que el ejecutable los detecte y en el caso de no ser detectados que se los pueda instalar mediante el mismo instalador.
Para eso visité varias paginas y videos pero no tuve los resultados que deseaba, estoy utilizando la extensión para Visual Studio 2017 Advanced installer, ya que me permite crear variables de entorno de manera mas fácil.

Comment: Es un poco complicado, hay que crear un Bootstrapper para el producto que quieres añadir como prerequisito. Mira [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32263776/579895)

Comment: Cuales son los requisitos previos que necesitas? son MSI? Sí no los tienes te retorna una ´ excepción ´ ?

Comment: Los requisitos previos son: Tener instalado Revit y TortoiseHg, si no están instalados, entonces que me de la opción de instalar desde el mismo programa.